# Airflow FileSensor taks is not working, alwasy in queue status

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I'm trying to sense file with airflow DAG, but my FileSensor is always stuck at queue status. I have tried with below code sample. Is there anything I'm missing? BTW, my airflow version is 2.0.1.

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator    import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import airflow

default_args = {
    "depends_on_past" : False,
    "start_date"      : datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=10)
}

with airflow.DAG( "fs_test_dag", default_args= default_args, schedule_interval= "@once"  ) as dag:
    start_task  = DummyOperator(  task_id= "start" )
    stop_task   = DummyOperator(  task_id= "stop"  )
    sensor_task = FileSensor( task_id= "file_sensor_task", poke_interval= 30,  filepath= "testfile.csv" )

start_task >> sensor_task  >> stop_task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please share queue name associated with the worker where you want to run this task. I do not see any queue name passed in task arguments, so airflow would expect a queue defined with same name `default_queue` in `airflow.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I mention the queue name in my filesersor task, now it's working. In my airflow default_queue was not configured.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue. The `FileSensor` is waiting for file in directory which can be specified in connection used by the operator. By default it is `~/` directory. Are you sure that the file is created in place where you expect it to be? Currently you sensor is waiting for `/testfile.csv` is that expected?

I created a dummy file and run you DAG and it run ok:

```
root@64299244fb44:/opt/airflow# touch /testfile.csv
root@64299244fb44:/opt/airflow# airflow dags backfill -s 2021-05-25 fs_test_dag
/opt/airflow/airflow/cli/commands/dag_command.py:62 PendingDeprecationWarning: --ignore-first-depends-on-past is deprecated as the value is always set to True
[2021-05-31 20:48:15,940] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /files/dags
[2021-05-31 20:48:16,736] {base_executor.py:82} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'start', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp8ttb6fz5']
[2021-05-31 20:48:21,476] {local_executor.py:81} INFO - QueuedLocalWorker running ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'start', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp8ttb6fz5']
[2021-05-31 20:48:21,488] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 0 of 1 | tasks waiting: 2 | succeeded: 0 | running: 1 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 2
[2021-05-31 20:48:21,531] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /files/dags/tasks.py
Running <TaskInstance: fs_test_dag.start 2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]> on host 64299244fb44
[2021-05-31 20:48:26,503] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 0 of 1 | tasks waiting: 2 | succeeded: 1 | running: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 2
[2021-05-31 20:48:26,527] {base_executor.py:82} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'file_sensor_task', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpbslxmgxo']
[2021-05-31 20:48:31,503] {local_executor.py:81} INFO - QueuedLocalWorker running ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'file_sensor_task', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpbslxmgxo']
[2021-05-31 20:48:31,516] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 0 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 1 | running: 1 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 1
[2021-05-31 20:48:31,547] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /files/dags/tasks.py
Running <TaskInstance: fs_test_dag.file_sensor_task 2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]> on host 64299244fb44
[2021-05-31 20:48:36,501] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 0 of 1 | tasks waiting: 1 | succeeded: 2 | running: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 1
[2021-05-31 20:48:36,527] {base_executor.py:82} INFO - Adding to queue: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'stop', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpvoqqs24l']
[2021-05-31 20:48:41,498] {local_executor.py:81} INFO - QueuedLocalWorker running ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'fs_test_dag', 'stop', '2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00', '--ignore-depends-on-past', '--local', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--subdir', '/files/dags/tasks.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpvoqqs24l']
[2021-05-31 20:48:41,512] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 0 of 1 | tasks waiting: 0 | succeeded: 2 | running: 1 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2021-05-31 20:48:41,542] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /files/dags/tasks.py
Running <TaskInstance: fs_test_dag.stop 2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]> on host 64299244fb44
[2021-05-31 20:48:46,520] {dagrun.py:444} INFO - Marking run <DagRun fs_test_dag @ 2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00: backfill__2021-05-25T00:00:00+00:00, externally triggered: False> successful
[2021-05-31 20:48:46,525] {backfill_job.py:388} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 1 of 1 | tasks waiting: 0 | succeeded: 3 | running: 0 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0
[2021-05-31 20:48:46,528] {local_executor.py:387} INFO - Shutting down LocalExecutor; waiting for running tasks to finish.  Signal again if you don't want to wait.
[2021-05-31 20:48:46,663] {backfill_job.py:831} INFO - Backfill done. Exiting.
```

Comment: For my case file is present in ~/ directory and always stuck in queued status. Even no log is generating for this task.

Comment: Interesting, what executor do you use? How do you create this file?

Comment: I mention the queue name in my filesersor task, now it's working. As if, in my airflow default_queue was not configured.  thanks for your help.